# Can the content:" "; have an image tag or say an image?

Tags: html, css, image, pseudo-element

Okay so I have been doing researches but still couldn't figure out if 'content:" ";' can contain images by any chance.

I don't whether my question is even appropriate or not. But would be happy to know if it could contain image links. Thanks.

For example I have an image tag as:

```
<img src="kitten.jpg">
```

Can I add this image in the content property?

```
:after {
  content:" ";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp, property values of `content`:

`url(url) | Sets the content to be some kind of media (an image, a sound, a video, etc.)`

So this will work:

```
.yourDiv:after { 
content: url('image-src'); 
}
```

Example snippet:

```css
p:after {
  content: url('https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4');
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some Stuff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please check the edited question and let me know if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, just use a forward slash to start at your server root and enter the path to the image wherever it is located on your server. For example:  `content: url('/images/kitten.png');`.

Answer (score 3):

CSS `content` can contain text or… images.

```
.seb-example:before {
    content: url('http://placekitten.com/250/250');
}
```

Although, I prefer to use `background-image` for `:before` (or `:after`) because it gives me more controle over size (with `background-size`). But on rare occasions I found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try it out?

You can use `url` to show an image. The `content` property will include any html content

See sample below:

```css
div,
div:after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div:after {
  content: url(http://placekitten.com/250/250);
}
```

```html
<div>image</div>
```

Comment: what if img src is just a name say  <img src="mountains.jpg">

Comment: i guess you can't have have markups (elements) in the `content` property- you would have to use `url` for that... `url(mountains.jpg)` will work

Comment: This deserves a +1 for actually using a kitten.